# angular selector document except specific

Tags: angularjs

i want select $document element except specific element(by class or id) in page via angular and without use jquery lib selector, how can do this, please help me?

$document.unbind('click', closeMenu);

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` is a native JavaScript call that works in all browsers

Comment: tnx, for answer, how can i select document except specific element

Comment: You would have to manually traverse the DOM - here's the first thing I found: http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom